# EF6 - Navigation property - single item instead of collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have following class setup:

```
public class GuestDefinition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GuestItem> GuestItems { get; set; }
}

public class GuestItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique =true)]
    public int InvitationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Invitation Invitation { get; set; }

    public int GuestDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public virtual GuestDefinition GuestDefinition { get; set; }
}

public class Invitation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual GuestItem GuestItem { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to apply following entity framework generates incorrect query

```
var entry = db.Invitations.Select(p => new
{
    Id = p.Id,
    Name = p.GuestItem.GuestDefinition.Name
}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Generated query from EF is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent3].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM   [dbo].[Invitation] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[GuestItems] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[GuestDefinition] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[GuestDefinitionId] = [Extent3].[Id]
WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
```

Problem lies on first join line, the correct join should be

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[GuestItems] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[InvitationId]
```

Is there any way how to make this work other than turning Invitation's GuestItem into an ICollection? Due to my use case, I'd like to prevent having to use FirstOrDefault() on each join call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You relationship is 1:1. In EF that technique is to define the non-principal ID as both KEY and FK. So for example:

```
public class GuestItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int GuestDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public virtual GuestDefinition GuestDefinition { get; set; }

    public virtual Invitation Invitation { get; set; }
}

public class Invitation
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("GuestItem")]
    public int GuestItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual GuestItem GuestItem { get; set; }
}
```

Or if you prefer fluent code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure GuestItemId as PK for GuestItem
    modelBuilder.Entity<GuestItem>()
        .HasKey(e => e.GuestItemId);

    // Configure GuestItemId as FK for GuestItem
    modelBuilder.Entity<GuestItem>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.Invitation) 
                .WithRequired(ad => ad.GuestItemId); 

}
```

See [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help, however, isn't there a way to map it using current setup? I'd like to avoid migrating data. 

I'm using a workaround by applying a LINQ join condition where I need this data, however navigation properties would be a more elegant solution

Comment: Navigation properties = relationships meaning you have to work with table keys. You are correct in that JOIN is the workaround.